# Issue with Postgres FDW Extension: Error importing foreign schema for join queries

Tags: postgresql, join

I am encountering an error while attempting to use the Postgres FDW extension to import a foreign schema from the same database server for performing join queries. Below, I have provided a snapshot of my pgAdmin for better clarity, along with a sample table creation script:

```
-- Create the enumerated type
CREATE TYPE UserType AS ENUM ('INTERNAL', 'EXTERNAL');

-- Create the User table using the enumerated type
CREATE TABLE "users" (
    id          SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    type        UserType,
    created_at  TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

To import the above database and its public schema into the "akil" database, I am using the following code:

```
CREATE SCHEMA temp_0_schema;

CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgres_fdw;

CREATE SERVER temp_0_server
FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw
OPTIONS (dbname 'temp_0', host 'localhost', port '5432');

CREATE USER MAPPING FOR CURRENT_USER
SERVER temp_0_server
OPTIONS (user 'akil', password '');

IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA public
FROM SERVER temp_0_server
INTO temp_0_schema;
```

However, I am encountering the following error:

```
ERROR:  type "public.usertype" does not exist
LINE 3:   type public.usertype OPTIONS (column_name 'type'),
               ^
QUERY:  CREATE FOREIGN TABLE users (
  id integer OPTIONS (column_name 'id') NOT NULL,
  type public.usertype OPTIONS (column_name 'type'),
  created_at timestamp without time zone OPTIONS (column_name 'created_at')
) SERVER temp_0_server
OPTIONS (schema_name 'public', table_name 'users');
CONTEXT:  importing foreign table "users" 

SQL state: 42704
```

I am having difficulty understanding the nature of the error and would appreciate any insights into what might be causing this issue.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The error means that you forgot to create `usertype` in the local database. Without that, how should the foreign table be defined? See what [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html#POSTGRES-FDW) has to say:

> It is generally recommended that the columns of a foreign table be declared with exactly the same data types, and collations if applicable, as the referenced columns of the remote table. Although `postgres_fdw` is currently rather forgiving about performing data type conversions at need, surprising semantic anomalies may arise when types or collations do not match, due to the remote server interpreting query conditions differently from the local server.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It would be great if you could take a look at my comment on @Zegarek's answer.

Comment: The answer is simple: you must not do that.

Answer (score 0):

It's [further down in the doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html#POSTGRES-FDW-OPTIONS-IMPORTING):

> If the remote tables to be imported have columns of user-defined data types, the local server must have compatible types of the same names.

Which means you need to set up matching user-defined types separately, as the extension doesn't handle that. Check the definition of `public.usertype` on your foreign server and define it the same one locally: in [`psql` client `\dT` meta-command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMAND-DT) displays the type definition, while [`\dt`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMAND-DE) can tell you what types a given table is defined with.

Comment: Thank you for your answer; I created compatible types on the local server. I realized that the issue arises during the import process, as it searches for the `usertype` in the `public` schema of the local server (as it is defined in the public schema of the foreign server). However, I have created them in the `temp_0_schema`. How can I import in such cases? I do not wish to create them in the public schema of the local server.

Comment: That sounds like a useful feature, but it's [not offered by `postgres_fdw`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html#POSTGRES-FDW-OPTIONS). You'll either have to move the types on the db you're importing from to `temp_0_schema` on there so that they match after import, or create them in `public` on the db your import to. If you want to handle tables like that later, you can put them in [`import foreign schema...except()` list](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-importforeignschema.html#id-1.9.3.151.6) and import them separately from the others.

Comment: If those are just `enum` types, you can define views that map those to regular `text`, and import those views instead of the underlying tables.